# Visual Basic Skipping If Statement

Tags: .net, vb.net

Please dont flag this as a duplicate the only threads i could find were on c++ and c# i need help with vb.

Im happy to report my game is pretty much completely functional however ive set it so when the player score value is 10 it pops up a victory dialog and asks if you want to play again and the same for if the computer score reaches 10 except its defeat

the if statement for the player is skipped because when the computer reaches 10 it pops up a defeat dialog but when the player reaches 10 the if statement isnt triggered

help?

```
Public Class gameForm
    Dim playerscore As Integer = 0
    Dim comscore As Integer = 0



    Private Sub btnPlay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click
        Try

            Dim rock = 3
            Dim paper = 2
            Dim scissors = 1
            Dim num As Integer = CInt(Int((3 * Rnd()) + 1))
            Randomize()


            ' IF PLAYER CHOOSES ROCK
            If rbRock.Checked And num = rock Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Rock"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Rock"
                lblOutcome.Text = "DRAW"
            ElseIf rbRock.Checked And num = paper Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Rock"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Paper"
                lblOutcome.Text = "YOU LOSE"
                comscore = comscore + 1
                lblComScoreVal.Text = CStr(comscore)
            ElseIf rbRock.Checked And num = scissors Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Rock"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Scissors"
                lblOutcome.Text = "YOU WIN"
                playerscore = playerscore + 1
                lblPlayerScoreVal.Text = CStr(playerscore)
            End If

            ' IF PLAYER CHOOSES PAPER
            If rbPaper.Checked And num = rock Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Paper"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Rock"
                lblOutcome.Text = "YOU WIN"
                playerscore = playerscore + 1
                lblPlayerScoreVal.Text = CStr(playerscore)
            ElseIf rbPaper.Checked And num = paper Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Paper"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Paper"
                lblOutcome.Text = "DRAW"
            ElseIf rbPaper.Checked And num = scissors Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Paper"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Scissors"
                lblOutcome.Text = "YOU LOSE"
                comscore = comscore + 1
                lblComScoreVal.Text = CStr(comscore)

            End If

            ' IF PLAYER CHOOSES SCISSORS

            If rbScissors.Checked And num = rock Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Scissors"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Rock"
                lblOutcome.Text = "YOU LOSE"
                comscore = comscore + 1
                lblComScoreVal.Text = CStr(comscore)
            ElseIf rbScissors.Checked And num = paper Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Scissors"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Paper"
                lblOutcome.Text = "YOU WIN"
                playerscore = playerscore + 1
                lblPlayerScore.Text = CStr(playerscore)
            ElseIf rbScissors.Checked And num = scissors Then
                lblPlayerChoice.Text = "You Chose Scissors"
                lblComChoice.Text = "Computer Chose Scissors"
                lblOutcome.Text = "DRAW"


            End If

            If playerscore = 10 Then
                Dim victory As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("You Won, Congratulations!" & vbCrLf & "Would You Like To Play Again?", "VICTORY", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                If victory = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    playerscore = 0
                    comscore = 0
                    lblPlayerScoreVal.Text = CStr(playerscore)
                    lblComScoreVal.Text = CStr(comscore)
                    lblPlayerChoice.Text = Nothing
                    lblComChoice.Text = Nothing
                    lblOutcome.Text = Nothing
                Else
                    Me.Close()
                End If
            End If

            If comscore = 10 Then
                Dim defeat As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("You Were Defeated, Unlucky!" & vbCrLf & "Would You Like To Play Again?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
                If defeat = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    playerscore = 0
                    comscore = 0
                    lblPlayerScoreVal.Text = CStr(playerscore)
                    lblComScoreVal.Text = CStr(comscore)
                    lblPlayerChoice.Text = Nothing
                    lblComChoice.Text = Nothing
                    lblOutcome.Text = Nothing
                Else
                    Me.Close()
                End If
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You are committing a hanging offence there.  You are catching absolutely any exception and simply ignoring it.  The most likely explanation for what you're seeing is that an exception is being thrown but you're just ignoring it so how would you know? Get rid of that exception handler altogether. You should NEVER add an exception handler unless you're expecting a particular type of exception to be able to be thrown under certain circumstances. NEVER add an exception handler like that just in case because the result is the mess you're in now.

Comment: when running through the code i noticed that i didnt try and set a window title for the defeat dialog but now i have that doesnt show up either what have i done? have i got the syntax order wrong?

Comment: Apart from that, learn how to debug and do it. You should be setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code to see EXACTLY what it's doing as it's doing it.  If you'd done that and an exception is being thrown then you'd have already seen where it happens and what the exception is.  If you don't know how to debug, start learning [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: if i take out the exeption handler it throws an invalidcast exception trying to turn the victory or defeat window title to an integer @jmcilhinney

Comment: On a less important note, learn how to generate random numbers properly.  If you are going to use `Randomize` and `Rnd` then do it properly, i.e. use `Randomize` once only, e.g. in the `Load` event handler.  That said, don't use `Randomize` and `Rnd`. We're not in VB6 anymore Toto.  Create a single instance of the `Random` class and use that to generate all your random numbers.

Comment: how do i do that @jmcilhinney?

Comment: "if i take out the exeption handler it throws an invalidcast exception". Um, it was throwing that exception anyway. That's the point. The solution is not to just ignore the exception. The solution is to work out why the exception is being thrown and fix the code that is throwing it. If an `InvalidCastException` is being thrown then obviously you are performing an invalid cast. What line is it thrown on, what are you casting and what type are you casting it as?

Comment: it was thrown on the line where i called the msgbox basically what i had done was put the window content the window title then the window button type, it wanted the window title to go last as it was trying to cast it as an integer for some reason i didnt see the exception in the console so i thought nothing of it

Comment: Like I said, don't add exception handling "just in case". All `Try...Catch` blocks should be for a specific purpose, e.g. in case a network connection goes down while connecting to a database or a file is deleted while trying to open it. Only stuff that is beyond your control.  For everything else, i.e. stuff that you didn't predict or the results of code bugs, you should handle the `UnhandledException` event of the application.  There you can log the error and exit the application gracefully, possibly even restarting automatically, rather than crashing. NEVER ignore an unknown exception.

Comment: Thank you, @jmcilhinney. I was just about to start my usual request to remove the `Catch ex As Exception` - you did a far better job than I. I'll just add a bit of light reading for the OP:  [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Answer (score 0):

when i put MsgBox("victory stuff here", "VICTORY", messageboxbuttons.yesno)
i was gettign the syntax wrong it would appear the window title is the last thing you put in a messagebox

Comment: You need to turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so it is the default for future projects.  After that, issues like this will be picked up by the compiler instead of at run time.  It won't solve all your problems but it will help force you to write better code by paying more attention to data types.

Comment: How do i do that @jmcilhinney

Comment: First you open a search engine, then you type in the appropriate keywords, then you read the relevant results, then you proceed based on the information you find.  If someone gives you keywords, your first action should ALWAYS be to find out what you can for yourself. Look first, ask questions later. We're not here to explain every little detail.

Comment: @JustARogueCoder - There's a default option, but you can always put `Option Strict On` as the first line of your code.

Comment: i literally just did that i found it in the options so this picks up on more errors? i didnt quite get what you said it does @jmcilhinney

Comment: @JustARogueCoder - It forces the compiler into a "strict" mode making VB.NET adhere to static type checking rather than having it hope to work at run-time. Think of it as shifting potential run-time errors to be compile-time errors instead.

Comment: @JustARogueCoder - On compile.

Comment: @Enigmativity is compile the build ?

Comment: @JustARogueCoder - Yes, that's right. When you build a solution you are compiling your code.